# Rest-auth :Exlamation mark comes before password

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using rest-auth for authentication.
after registration when I try to login it show

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
    ]
}
```

and when I saw the user on admin panel an an '!' mark comed before password for example
password ='!72wlGF0RiGRraz69sveb63FUrebNkAW9xmOoL16C'
please help

Comment: If you have seen the password as *plain text*, that's terrible since password hashing didn't take place

Comment: I am beginner here.Can you show me how?